# Generalized Mixins

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, mixins, variadic-templates

I was writing some code where I have a class that can accept mixins as variadic template parameters. However, I also need the mixins to be able to access the base class through the CRTP idiom. Here's a minimal example that cannot quite do what I want:

```
template <template <class> class... Mixins>
class Foo : Mixins<Foo<Mixins...>>... {};
```

However, a mixin that I might pass to `Foo` will, in general, have several template parameters, like so:

```
template <class Derived, class Type1, class Type2>
class Bar
{
    Derived& operator()()
    {
        return static_cast<Derived&>(*this);
    }
};
```

How can I change `Foo` so that I can have it inherit from a number of base classes, where I control the template parameters accepted by each base class? If I hand `Foo` a list of template-template parameters, along with a list of arguments to pass to them, then I don't see how I would be able to associate each template-template parameter with its arguments. So far, I thought of something like this, but I don't know how I would proceed.

```
template <template <class...> class T,
    template <class...> class... Ts>
class Foo : /* How do I retrieve the arguments? */
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not quite sure I understood the problem, so please let me rephrase it so that we can start on the right foot.

You need to thread the derived type to the base classes, in a typical CRTP use case, while at the same time passing other template parameter to the various base classes.

That is, a typical base class will be:

```
template <typename Derived, typename X, typename Y>
struct SomeBase {
};
```

And you want need to create your type so that you can control the `X` and `Y` and at the same time pass the complete `Derived` class.

---

I think I would use the `apply` trick to generate the base class on the fly, from an adapter provided in the argument list of the `Derived` class.

```
template <typename Derived, typename X, typename Y>
struct SomeBase {};

template <typename X, typename Y>
struct SomeBaseFactory {
  template <typename Derived>
  struct apply { typedef SomeBase<Derived, X, Y> type; };
};

// Generic application
template <typename Fac, typename Derived>
struct apply {
  typedef typename Fac::template apply<Derived>::type type;
};
```

Then, you would create the type as:

```
typedef MyFoo< SomeBaseFactory<int, float> > SuperFoo;
```

Where `Foo` is defined as:

```
template <typename... Args>
struct Foo: apply<Args, Foo<Args...>>::type... {
};
```

And just because it's been a while since I trudged so deeply in templates, [I checked it worked](http://ideone.com/v1D5B).

---

Of course, the `Factory` itself is not really a specific to a given type, so we can reuse the wrapper approach you had experimented:

```
template <template <typename...> class M, typename... Args>
struct Factory {
  template <typename Derived>
  struct apply { typedef M<Derived, Args...> type; };
};
```

And yes, [it works too](http://ideone.com/dndKO).

Comment: This is clearly the most elegant solution; sorry if my question was a little ambiguous.

Comment: @void-pointer: I would not necessarily say ambiguous, there were several layers to dig through so I thought best to clearly express the problem I was trying to solve, so that you could correct me if I headed in the wrong direction :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you should create template aliases that reduce each mixin to a single template parameter.

```
template <typename Derived>
using BarIntFloat = Bar<Derived, Int, Float>;

template <typename Derived>
using BazQux = Baz<Derived, Qux>;

typedef Foo<BarIntFloat, BazQux> MyFoo;
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of using template aliases to accomplish this -- thanks for the answer. One caveat is that things get inconvenient as more mixins need to be used. I came up with a hack that seems to work without template aliases, but perhaps there's a better way to do it?

Comment: I think you need a template alias to get CRTP, but you may wrap it into your wrapper to get something nice and easy to use. Sorry, I have no compiler that supports aliases at the moment so I cannot test.

Comment: Hm, my solution seems to work as expected without template aliases, though I don't have a compiler that supports template aliases yet. g++ 4.7 does, but I'd like to wait until the official release.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I came up with. There may be a more elegant way to do this, but I couldn't think of any. One caveat is that all of the mixins used need to first be nested in the `wrapper` struct, along with their respective arguments.

```
template <template <class...> class Mixin, class... Args>
struct wrapper
{
        typedef Mixin<Args...> type;
};

template <class... Args>
struct test
{

};

template <class Arg, class... Args>
struct test<Arg, Args...> : Arg::type, test<Args...>
{

};

template <class T>
class mixin1 {};

template <class T1, class T2>
class mixin2 {};

template <class T1, class T2, class T3>
class mixin3 {};

int main()
{
        test<wrapper<mixin1, int>, wrapper<mixin2, int, float>> foo;
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@void-pointer

This is basic omission of variadic templates. User cannot get i-th type from T... or get i-th value from values...

Here is [a link](http://ecn.channel9.msdn.com/events/GoingNative12/GN12VariadicTemplatesAreFunadic.pdf) from going native 2012 lecture by Andrei Alexandrescu:

```
template <typename... Ts>
void fun(const Ts&... vs) {}
```

• Ts is not a type; vs is not a value!

```
typedef Ts MyList; // error!
Ts var; // error!
auto copy = vs; // error!
```

So Ts/vs should be some kind of tuple.

Comment: I think you somewhat missed the question, I didn't see any hint that an access by index was expected.

Comment: "User cannot get i-th type from T..." -- easy, just unpack the `T...` into a `std::tuple` and use `std::tuple_element`. Same vor `values...`.